# Proper way to pass a controller to a Component

Tags: ember.js

Ok, I'm trying to get at a computed property on a random controller (not my template's default controller) to pass this property into a component on a random template. With some help on irc I was pointed to: "http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/" and realized my question was more of a controller dependency question than a component question, this helped but I'm still having issues.

So on my blah template's default controller (BlahController) I use the 'needs' hook to get access to the FooBarController like this:

```
needs: 'foo_bar'
```

And in the same blah template where I'm calling my component, I get at the FooBarController's property like such:

```
{{my-widget someProperty=controllers.foo_bar.someProperty}}
```

And my component just displays the property like such:

```
{{someProperty}}
```

The property (someProperty) I'm trying to access is a computed property with it's own dependancies. I get an error that the dependent properties on the computed property don't seem to be available???

Answer (score 0):

Ember components are to be only used when you need completely isolated views to build       re-usable ui elements. So, all content that a component needs for its template must be passed in when you invoke the component as parameters. A component should not be bound to a controller. Instead, when it needs to propagate events, it should use the 'sendAction' api to whichever controller controls the template it is invoked in. What you really need is a view.

Comment: Hi Hrishi, I just edited my original question. I managed to get closer but then ran into another wall. But thanks for your help. I guess it seems weird to me that I wouldn't be able to have a component that is spitting out a computed property from some controller? That seems a reasonable thing to want to do with a component. I also thought in practice components were more favorable to use over a view since they make things more succinct in your templates...but back to the view I must go, I guess.

Comment: That just returned the string "controllers.whatever" to my template. Without the quotes is definitely accessing the computed property on the controller because I'm getting: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'height' of undefined in this case height is a property on the computed property I'm after. Dare I say this seems like a bug.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, seeing this : http://emberjs.com/guides/components/passing-properties-to-a-component/ , it seems like you should pass in the property like    {{my-widget someProperty=controller.controllers.foo_bar.someProperty}}

Comment: Yep, that is the "answer," sadly I can't vote a +1 since I'm still new to SO. But thanks! And that error I was getting was a different issue, nothing to do with passing the controller property to the component.